# Is there a module for using Google Analytics to display popular content?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm actually looking to make a simplier version of the [Radioactivity](https://www.drupal.org/project/radioactivity) module.

I wonder if there are any modules out there that are using Google statistics to display content.

Comment: check if it help https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter

Comment: [Here](http://www.jasom.net/google-analytics-counter-how-to-get-client-id-and-client-secret-bonus)'s the setup tutorial for Google Analytics Counter (GAC) module.

Answer (score 4):

[Google Analytics Statistics](https://drupal.org/project/ga_stats) has integration with views...

Project page says

> This module provides views integration for the Google Analytics Data
>   Export API.
>
> This allows you to use Google Analytics directly through views to do
>   things like Most Popular, Most Read ect. You can combine the
>   statistics to create interesting results.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [Drupal Most Popular Module](https://drupal.org/project/mostpopular)

> The module is pre-packaged with several services including: Google
>   Analytics - Most Viewed pages
>
> 1. Create any number of Most Popular widget blocks, displaying any combination of services and intervals.
> 2. Customize the maximum number of results to display for each block.
> 3. Show or hide the number of page hits for most popular items.

Answer (score 2):

There's a module called [Google Analytics Counter](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter). This is from its project page:

> *Views integration with any of the storage tables. If using the module's table, to add the counter values for nodes to your view you
>   just need to add field "Pageview Total". Sorting and filtering by the
>   counter values works as well. **This for example allows you to show
>   nodes sorted by their popularity!***.

[Here](http://www.jasom.net/google-analytics-counter-how-to-get-client-id-and-client-secret-bonus) you can learn how to configure it.